# ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not permitted

Tags: sql, database, derby

Is there any wrong in this query operations basically i am retrieving one column text of a table and then again i am giving retrieved information to 
access other contents of the same table but the problem here is the first query executes only once and then it throws exception with this message
 "ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF". i don't understand properly why it is throwing this exception.

this is the query throwing exception

```
rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT  k from document order by k asc ");
                    while(rs.next()){
                    ...
                    }
```

full code snippet is here

```
try{
                 rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT  k from document order by k asc ");

                    while(rs.next()){

                System.out.println(".................."+rs.getString(1));

                rss=s.executeQuery("SELECT  k,  num, fre, spm from document where k='"+rs.getString(1)+"' order by k asc");

                rsmd = rss.getMetaData();
                 columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();  

                for (i=1; i<=columnsNumber; i++)
                {
                    //print Column Names
                    System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+"\t\t");  
                }
                 while (rss.next()) {


                    for(i = 1 ; i <= columnsNumber; i++){
                          System.out.print(rss.getString(i) + "\t\t"); //Print one element of a row
                    }

                }
                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
```

Let me know if someone has an answer for this and let me know how to overcome from this problem thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Can you please change the statement object to a new one for the inner query

something like

for inner query

rss=newStatement.executeQuery("SELECT  ////

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(".................."+**rs.getString(1));**

rss=s.executeQuery("SELECT  k,  num, fre, spm from document where k='"+**rs.getString(1)+"**' order by k asc");
```

You have used rs.getString(1)) twice. this creates the problem. Please store the value of rs.getString(1) into an object and use it .

something like

```
String str = rs.getString(1);

System.out.println(".................."+str);

rss=s.executeQuery("SELECT  k,  num, fre, spm from document where k='"+str+"' order by k asc");
```

Additional can you please change the statement object to a new one for the inner query

Comment: I did what you said but results are same no change.

Comment: You can use `getString()` as often as you want.